# BASH: loop for files with or without leading zeros

Tags: file, shell, loops, rename, zero

I wan't to rename (or process) files in a directory (with specific extension).
Filenames can be anything containing ordering numbers like

```
1.aaa.txt
aa 1.txt
aa01bb.txt
78aa1bbb.txt
78aa2bbb.txt
```

Numbering with or without leading zero and new filename resulting without.

So I have:

```
NUM=0; for f in *.txt; do NUM=`expr $NUM + 1`; mv "$f" "yyy_$NUM.txt"; done
```

How to have the loop also understanding file order with files numbered without leading zeros 1,2..10,11..etc.?

Thanks.

Comment: *How to have the loop also understanding file order with files numbered without leading zeros 1,2..10,11..etc.?* Parse error. Can you rephrase or provide a specific example what the file names should be?

Comment: What's the relevant number in `78aa1bbb.txt`? 78 or 1?

Answer (score 1):

The following Python code should do the ordering stuff:

```
import re
from glob import glob

files = sorted([ file[:-4] for file in glob('*.txt') ])

chunked = []

for i, file in enumerate(files):
    chunks = re.split('(\d+)', file)
    for j, chunk in enumerate(chunks):
        if chunk.isdigit():
            chunks[j] = int(chunk)
    chunked.append((chunks, i))

for chunk, i in sorted(chunked):
    print(files[i])
```

Whith a dir that looks like this:

```
$ ls
01aa.txt  21a.txt  aa01bb.txt   aa10bb.txt
21aa.txt  2aa.txt  aa023bb.txt  aa1bb.txt
```

It outputs:

```
01aa.txt
2aa.txt
21a.txt
21aa.txt
aa01bb.txt
aa1bb.txt
aa10bb.txt
aa023bb.txt
```

This is different from what outputs a simple `sort`.

```
$ ls | sort
01aa.txt
21aa.txt
21a.txt
2aa.txt
aa01bb.txt
aa023bb.txt
aa10bb.txt
aa1bb.txt
```